# React JS Prevent word-break for Text nested in Row

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm new to React. I'm displaying a dynamic list of text inside a Row.

```
<Row>
   {namelist.map(name => <Text>{name}</Text>)}
</Row>
```

Current behavior:

> Nathan John James Char
> les Tim David

So basically word-break happens when space ran out for , it wraps and causing the Text beneath to break the words. Is there a way that I can achieve this instead:

> Nathan John James
> Charles Tim David

That is the Text should always be displayed as a whole, either in the current row or in a new row when there is insufficient space in the current row.

I have tried `whitespace: nowrap`, `flex-wrap:nowrap`, `word-wrap:normal` but they are all not working. I'm wondering is it the problem with the Row or the Text?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is having it like this.

```
 {namelist.map((name) => {return (<Row><Text>{name}</Text></Row>)})}
```